# Handling Many Buttons in JavaFX

Tags: button, javafx, switch-statement, case, handle

Let's say I have a JavaFX application and want to change between scenes. Each scene contains Buttons, which, when pressed, lead to the following scenes.

In order to give my buttons commands what to do if pressed, I try to do the following:

```
for (Button button : buttonsArray) //for each Button in ArrayList
    button.setOnAction( e -> handle(frameID, button.ID) ); 
    //give it the data about frame and button
```

The problem is, the `handle` method contains huge amount of Switch-Case statements:

```
switch (frameID)  //lokking for a certain frame
{
    case 1: switch (ID)  // and a certain button
            {
             case 1: // lead to the certain scene 
             break;
            } break;
}
```

Not even it complicates the code, it's also really easy to spoil everything by writing brackets or `break` wrong. It also feels a bit like garbage code.

So, what's the better way to manage all these buttons? I'm relatively new to Java and OOP, though I'm open to learn new things.

Comment: Edit the question to include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), complete minimal code, that somebody could just copy and paste to run and reproduce your functionality.  It wouldn't need to include all your switch IDs, just maybe about four of them so that it is representative of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

why not adding the buttons from scene builder then add an action for each button

```
public void button1Action(ActionEvent event)
{do some work }
```

`public void button2Action(ActionEvent event)
{
//do some work 
}`

[image]

Comment: you probably want to add some details as to how exactly that can be done :)

Answer (score 0):

try to create an action event for each button

```
public void PressButton(ActionEvent action){
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("YourFXML.fxml"));
            Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
}
```